# Gmail Label Error

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

How can I not have the emails of a gmail label show up in my inbox?

I know this has been posted before, but I will elaborate.

I have 2 gmail accounts (lets call them A and B), I am always logged into A.
When receiving a message from B, I have a filter that applies a label to it, but somehow it also shows up in the inbox for the account A.

Basically, it as applying 2 labels to incoming mail: 'Inbox' and 'Account B'

The filter has 'skip inbox' checked.

It never used to do it, and it doesn't do it for all mail to that account.

Any help will be much appreciated, as this is driving me nuts

Answer (score 1):

If the skip inbox is checked, It should work ... it is working fine for me.

Maybe you should check the [inbox setting](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?hl=fr&shva=1#settings/inbox)

Is your priority inbox is enabled?  I know that if it is enabled, it can show some mail not in the inbox as important.